# Можете пожалуйста помочь с программой?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю как это делать. Может кто-то знает как делать. Срочно нужно. У меня есть набросок кода но не уверен в верности. Вычисления произведения квадратной матрицы на вектор.

```
import random

n = int(input('n='))
x = [0] * n
z = [0] * n
a = []

for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    for k in range(n):
        t = random.randint(0, 20)
        a[i].append(t)
        x[k] = random.randint (0, 20)

for i in range (0, n, 1):
    z[i] = a[i] * x[i]

print(z)
```

Comment: Код покажи ;)...

Comment: import random

n = int(input('n='))
x = [0]*n
z = [0]*n
a = []

for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    for k in range(n):
        t=random.randint(0,20)
        a[i].append(t)
        x[k]=random.randint (0,20)

for i in range (0,n,1):
    z[i]=a[i]*x[i]

print (z)

Comment: а как код нормально кинуть

Comment: Кнопкой править под вопросом ;)

Comment: спасибо я не давно на сайте

Comment: для чего нужен первый цикл?

Comment: делает  двумерный массив если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: `z = [sum(arr) * n for arr, n in zip(zip(*a), x)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если матрица точно квадратная, и если вам запрещено пользоваться  numpy, то примерно вот так:

```
a=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,34,25]]
x=[1,2,3,4,5]

z=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
    z_t=0
    for k in range(len(a)):
        z_t=z_t+a[i][k]*x[k]
    z.append(z_t)
print(z)
```

Результат:

```
[55, 130, 205, 280, 395]
```

Comment: спасибо помогло

Comment: "Спасибо" на этом сайте принято выражать несколько иначе. Как и "помогло", кстати -  тоже. Впрочем -  смотрю, вы не очень этим заморачиваетесь.

Comment: Ой тогда извините  я на сайте недавно, в преть буду выражаться нормально.

Comment: @Lisha да не "выражаться"  надо, а кнопки нажимать. Как я смотрю - вы этого никогда не делаете.